# Query with Django ORM (joining models?)

Tags: django, orm

I have the following models:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Post(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This is for my forum system.

I need to fetch all the `Thread`s of category X and I need to have a few custom attributes like `datetime` and `pk` of the last post to the thread, for example:

```
threads = Thread.objects.filter(category=x)
last_post = Post.objects.filter(thread=threads[0]).order_by('-pk')[0]
```

Then I want to transfer everything to the template so that I get:

```
{{ t.pk }} as thread_pk
{{ t.last_post_pk }} as last_post_pk
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

To get last post for every thread you should use aggregation:

```
Post.objects.filter(thread__in=threads).values('thread').annotate(last_id=Max('id')).order_by()
```

This will get you `last_id` from every thread in `threads`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Django doesn't do joining like you would expect with SQL joins (see my comment for further explanation), I would solve it in the view (or perhaps a method added to the `Thread` class). Consider the following example view:

```
def index(request):
    res = []
    for t in Thread.objects.filter(category__name='x'):
        res.append((t, Post.objects.filter(thread=t).order_by('-datetime')[0]))
    # Optionally sort by datetime here:
    # res.sort(key=lambda x: x[1].datetime, reverse=True)
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'result': res})
```

You could then use it in the template as follows:

```
{% for r in res %}
    Thread {{ r.0.name }}, last post by {{ r.1.author.name }} on {{ r.1.datetime }}.
{% endfor %}

# This would give something like this:
# Thread mythread, last post by john on Oct. 21, 2011, 1:52 a.m..
```

By creating a tuple of `Thread`s and `Post`s, you don't really join them, but do make them easily available in the template.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by not supporting SQL-like joins... your line 3 can be written as `Thread.objects.filter(category__name='x')'. Avoiding some joins for optimization reasons is another matter entirely.

Comment: @BéresBotond: I meant that Django doesn't create a new, joined, dataset as everything has to be known in the ORM to be able to access the result set. It does indeed support joins (I'll reword it in the answer), but not in the SQL-sense: Django does something along the lines of traversing related models.